# Imported wordpress theme but its now working

Tags: wordpress

today ı bought an wordpress theme and imported. It is name listivo. After import i activate that theme and required plugins. When ı check site its seems diffrent site , its look like very basic. I checked themes folder, css and scripts they are there but on the web site unlike folder. I cant see that theme correctly I dont know where is the problem can you help me ?
it seems like that https://listifycyprus.com/wp/

I reset the wordpress then import that again but its still same https://listifycyprus.com/wp/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there might be a compatibility or configuration issue with the imported theme and required plugins.

Firstly, make sure that all the required plugins are properly activated and up-to-date. If the appearance of the site is different from what you expected, it could be due to missing or incorrect settings within the theme or its customization options.